# Intel xdk 2 barcode scanners

Tags: javascript, html, intel-xdk

I'm trying to implement 2 barcode scanners to 2 diffrent buttons. The problem is that when I press one or the other button, both scripts are being used with each button. How I need to seperate them?

Button 1:

```
<a class="uib-graphic-button default-graphic-sizing default-image-sizing hover-graphic-button active-graphic-button default-graphic-button default-graphic-text widget uib_w_52 d-margins skenavimo_tekstas media-button-text-bottom" data-uib="media/graphic_button"
                data-ver="0" id="scan1" style="position: relative; display:block; float:center; width: 10%; padding-bottom: 10%;
width: 50%; margin: 0 auto; " onclick="scanNow();">
```

Button 2:

```
<a class="button widget uib_w_54 d-margins testas icon camera yellow" data-uib="app_framework/button" data-ver="1" id="scan2" onclick="scanNow2();">Scan</a>
```

Script1:

```
 <script>
        function scanNow()
            {
                //this function launches the QR Code scanner.
                intel.xdk.device.scanBarcode();
            }
            document.addEventListener("intel.xdk.device.barcode.scan",function(evt){
                if (evt.success == true) {
                    //successful scan
                   alert("I'm number 1");
                }
                else 
                {
                    //failed scan
                    alert("ERROR");
                }
            },false);
    </script>
```

Script2:

```
<script>
    function scanNow2()
            {
                //this function launches the QR Code scanner.
                intel.xdk.device.scanBarcode();
            }
   document.addEventListener("intel.xdk.device.barcode.scan",function(ted){
                if (ted.success == true) {
                    //successful scan
                alert("I'm nubmer 2");
                }else{
               //failed scan
                    alert("ERROR");
                }
             },false);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 event handlers registered in code, so both get triggered when u call `intel.xdk.device.scanBarcode();` You should have one event handler and handle the 2 cases in the event handler like below:

```
<script>

var scan = 0; 

function scanNow(){
    scan = 1;
    intel.xdk.device.scanBarcode();
}

function scanNow2(){
    scan = 2;
    intel.xdk.device.scanBarcode();
}

document.addEventListener("intel.xdk.device.barcode.scan",function(ted){
    if (ted.success == true) {
        if(scan == 1){
            scan = 0;
            alert("I'm number 1");
        } else if(scan == 2){
            scan = 0;
            alert("I'm number 2");
        }
    }else{
        alert("ERROR");
    }
},false); 

</script>
```